# PowerShell with a configuration script

Tags: powershell

Needs some help. We run PowerShell scripts using a configuration script.

e.g. .\folderA\TheConfigurationScript .\scriptThatDoesAllTheWork.ps1

The issue is that in the directory where scriptThatDoesAllTheWork.ps1 is located there are number of other scripts.

If I accidentally add a space before scriptThatDoesAllTheWork.ps1 all scripts located in that folder are executed

e.g. .\folderA\TheConfigurationScript 
.\ scriptThatDoesAllTheWork.ps1

All variables therefore defined in folderA\TheConfigurationScript are available to scriptThatDoesAllTheWork.ps1 that does all the work

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does `TheConfigurationScript` parse its parameters?

Comment: My spidey-sense tells me you're using ```Get-ChildItem``` in ```TheConfigurationScript``` with the first parameter used as the path to find the target script(s) to run, and then running all the items that match. When you call it *without* a space it's effectively doing ```Get-ChildItem ".\scriptThatDoesAllTheWork.ps1"```, but *with* a space it's being treated as two parameters and the first is used as the path, equivalent to ```Get-ChildItem ".\"``` which returns all the files in the folder.

Comment: You can probably either enclose the parameter in quotes - e.g. ```.\folderA\TheConfigurationScript ".\ scriptThatDoesAllTheWork.ps1"``` to catch the typo or add some error handling in ```TheConfigurationScript``` to prevent it running if it finds multiple files.

Comment: Please edit the question and include relevant parts of `TheConfigurationScript`. The problem is likely in argument parsing, but without any code, it's just guessing.

Comment: @mclayton. Spot on. I had a get-childitem from ages ago which is why I didn't remember. Thanks. For the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mclayton. I had a get-childitem that would return all the files in case of space. In case this helps anyone